# Is it necessary to import actionscript files through timeline actions?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

It seems as though every actionscript file (not custom ones) is automatically included when coding in the timeline's actions, so I'm wondering if it's necessary to import the files through the code.  Are there any advantages?  Can I prevent flash from importing every file to reduce the size of my flash application (SWF)?.

For example, I don't need to import `MovieClip` to use the `MovieClip` class in timeline actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed load external assets, that is, anything of SWF, MP3, WAV, JPG or any byte sequence you have a decoder for, then parse it via code, then use in your Flash app. The advantages are flexibility, for example, if a user has all sounds turned off, you are free to not load large music for him thus saving him some traffic - this might be crucial for some people out there. There are also disadvantages, because the files (assets) in SWF are available from the start of your app, and because the connection can get lost at any moment, you might not receive your external files in time for the app to use, or not receive them at all.

Not importing in order to reduce the SWF size? I'd say reduce the size or quality of those assets instead. The actual mess with `Loader`s is something you should avoid unless you have dynamic downloadable content (some extra levels' metadata maybe) which you plan to generate on a timely basis in order to attract longer attention to your app.

In short, all static content is better embedded, all dynamic content should be loaded afterwards.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking at all.  I'm saying flash automatically imports every actionscript file, so can I stop it from doing that so I can only import the files I *need* to reduce the swf size?

Comment: If you explicitly reference a class in your code, it is imported, period. If you don't explicitly reference a class, it is not, another period. Say you wrote `import flash.display.*;` this does **not** mean that say `Bitmap` is included in the SWF - it's just became available to the compiler and you can reference it in code. If you don't, then no code for bitmaps is embedded. But if you write somewhere `var b:Bitmap`, then `Bitmap` is imported.

Comment: Vesper, I'm not an idiot.  I am not use OOP.  I'm saying every asset is imported, even though you there's no `import` keyword in the code **at all** when using timeline animation.

Comment: "Every asset is imported"? Try checking the size of your compiled SWF, then remove one of your assets from timeline entirely, while leaving it in the library, and compile again. The size should decrease. If so, see the post. If not, then it's weird, and you are probably searching for Flash CSx setting that controls what's imported and what's not. I don't know such settings as I don't have deep experience with Flash CSx.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't explaining clearly enough.  I *am* using Flash CSx, I clearly said ***'timeline'*** actions.  What I'm saying is there's imports like flash.display.MovieClip that don't need to be imported in order to use

Comment: The code isn't duplicated anyway, if you have `flash.display.MovieClip` instances in you SWF, and `MainTimeline` is a `MovieClip`, the code from `flash.display.MovieClip` import will be present in your SWF, but only one time, regardless of how many *.as files you have that have `import flash.display.MovieClip` line in them. IN fact `import` is only a compiler directive, so that it knows where to find class description, in which package, so that if you write `var mc:MovieClip` it'll get linked to `flash.display` package.

Comment: MainTimeline, a: starts with a capitol letter so isn't a MovieClip, and b: The main timeline is something in the flash IDE

Answer (score 0):

Compiling FLA file doesn't embed every AS file in the resulting SWF. My test directory structure.

Work Directory

- file.fla
- ClassA.as
- ClassB.as

The code on my timeline.

```
var a:ClassA = new ClassA();
```

The resulting SWF only contain the ClassA.

For multiple SWF files with code, every SWF embed the class. It's your job to tell the compiler.

If you are using FLEXSDK, you can look to these parameters.
-link-report file.xml : Generate a file containing all AS file include at compilation.
-load-externs file.xml : Exclude all class containt in the file.

If you are using Adobe Flash [exclude class article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=07_classes_54.html)

Comment: Not custom classes, I'm saying that, for example, you don't need to import `MovieClip` in timeline code to use the `MovieClip` class

Comment: In external editor, you need to specify the import statement unless you put all classes in default package (no package name). All the flash package is not compile in the SWF, this class is in the Flash Player directly.

Comment: That's my point, I'm not using an external editor.  I'm using the main timeline in the Flash CSX Professional IDE.